# Почему Room in android не работает? Помогите пожалуйста я не понимаю почему не вставляются данные?

Tags: android, room

Класс бизнес.

```
@Entity(tableName = "database")
public class Business {

    @PrimaryKey
    public int id;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "amount")
    public int amount;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "price")
    public int price;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "time")
    public int time;

    public Business(int id,  int amount, int price, int time) {
        this.id = id;
        this.amount = amount;
        this.price = price;
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

Dao objects.

```
@Dao
public interface BusinessDao {
    @Query("SELECT * FROM `database`")
    List<Business> getAll();

    @Query("SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE id = :id")
    Business getById(long id);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE id IN (:BusinessIds)")
    List<Business> loadAllByIds(int[] BusinessIds);

    @Insert
    void insertAll(Business... businesses);

    @Update
    void update(Business... business);

    @Query("SELECT * FROM `database` WHERE id == :id")
    public  Business getBusiness(int id);

    @Delete
    void delete(Business business);

    @RawQuery
    Business getUserViaQuery(SupportSQLiteQuery query);
}
```

DataBase

```
@Database(entities = {Business.class}, version = 1)
public abstract class AppDatabase extends RoomDatabase {


    public abstract BusinessDao businessDao();
}
```

class App

```
public class App extends Application {

    public static App instance;

    private AppDatabase database;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        instance = this;
        database = Room.databaseBuilder(this, AppDatabase.class, "database")
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .build();
    }

    public static App getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public AppDatabase getDatabase() {
        return database;
    }
}
```

MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements BusinessFragment.onImageClickListener {


    private int mAllMoney = 4;
    private int mAmountOfProduction;

    private List<Business> mListOfData;




    private AppDatabase mAppDatabase;
    private BusinessDao businessDao;
    private TextView mTextViewMoney = null;
    private final Handler handler = new Handler();

    private BusinessFragment firstBusinessFragment = new BusinessFragment();
    private BusinessFragment secondBusinessFragment = new BusinessFragment();
    private BusinessFragment thirdBusinessFragment = new BusinessFragment();
    private BusinessFragment fourthBusinessFragment = new BusinessFragment();
    private BusinessFragment fifthBusinessFragment = new BusinessFragment();

    private Business firstBusiness;
    private Business secondBusiness;
    private Business thirdBusiness;
    private Business fourthBusiness;
    private Business fifthBusiness;


    private boolean isDataBaseExist ;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        mTextViewMoney = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.amount);


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                mAppDatabase = App.getInstance().getDatabase();
                 businessDao = mAppDatabase.businessDao();

                if (businessDao.getAll() == null) {
                    isDataBaseExist = false;
                } else {
                    isDataBaseExist = true;
                    mListOfData = businessDao.getAll();
                }
            }
        });


       if (isDataBaseExist) {

            firstBusinessFragment.setmBusiness(mListOfData.get(0));
           secondBusinessFragment.setmBusiness(mListOfData.get(1));
            thirdBusinessFragment.setmBusiness(mListOfData.get(2));
            fourthBusinessFragment.setmBusiness(mListOfData.get(3));
            fifthBusinessFragment.setmBusiness(mListOfData.get(4));
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.first_business, firstBusinessFragment)
                   .replace(R.id.second_business, secondBusinessFragment)
                    .replace(R.id.third_business, thirdBusinessFragment)
                    .replace(R.id.fourth_business, fourthBusinessFragment)
                    .replace(R.id.fifth_business, fifthBusinessFragment)
                    .commit();
           Log.i("fjkvjf","i am in if");
       } else {
           Log.i("fjkvjf","i am in else");

           firstBusiness = new Business(0, 4, 4, 3);
           secondBusiness = new Business(1, 4, 50, 8);
           thirdBusiness = new Business(2, 4, 500, 15);
           fourthBusiness = new Business(3, 4, 10000, 40);
           fifthBusiness = new Business(4, 4, 500000, 80);


             new Thread(new Runnable() {
                 @Override
                 public void run() {
                     businessDao.insertAll(firstBusiness,secondBusiness,thirdBusiness,fourthBusiness,fifthBusiness);
                 }
             }) ;

            firstBusinessFragment.setmBusiness(firstBusiness);
            secondBusinessFragment.setmBusiness(secondBusiness);
            thirdBusinessFragment.setmBusiness(thirdBusiness);
            fourthBusinessFragment.setmBusiness(fourthBusiness);
            fifthBusinessFragment.setmBusiness(fifthBusiness);
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .add(R.id.first_business, firstBusinessFragment)
                    .add(R.id.second_business, secondBusinessFragment)
                    .add(R.id.third_business, thirdBusinessFragment)
                    .add(R.id.fourth_business, fourthBusinessFragment)
                    .add(R.id.fifth_business, fifthBusinessFragment)
                    .commit();
        }
    }


    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        Log.i("yLogDebugger", "onPause was called ");
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        Log.i("myLogDebugger", "onStop was called ");
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // updateDataBase();
        Log.i("yLogDebugger", "onDestroy was called ");
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onImageSelected(int mAddedMoney) {

        mAllMoney += mAddedMoney;
        mTextViewMoney.setText("Деньги " + Integer.toString(mAllMoney) + "$");
    }


    @Override
    public void onTextViewOfPriceSelected(int price, int amountOfProduction) {
          mAllMoney = mAllMoney - price;
          mTextViewMoney.setText("Деньги"+Integer.toString(mAllMoney)+ "$" );
    }

    private int getCurrentTime() {
        Date date = new Date();
        return (int) date.getTime();
    }

    private void updateDataBase(final Business business){


        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                businessDao.update(business);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void sendDataToUpdate(int id, int amount, int price, int time) {

        updateDataBase(new Business(id,amount,price,time));


    }
}
```

Comment: Наверное при пустой базе `businessDao.getAll()` возвращает пустой список, а не `null` и соответственно условие добавления данных не срабатывает. По-хорошему начальные данные надо добавлять в [колбеке базы](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/room/RoomDatabase.Builder.html#addCallback(androidx.room.RoomDatabase.Callback))

Comment: Спасибо. Но он переходит в ветку else где прописано добавление данных.

Comment: Тогда что не так? Условие срабатывает каждый раз? Тогда дело не в базе, а в непонимании многопоточности - переменная `isDataBaseExist` проверяется раньше, чем ей присваивается правильное значение в другом потоке. И вы, кстати, этот поток даже не запускаете (нет вызова `start()`)

Comment: Спасибо огромное, разобрался